# USB storage emulator

Tags: .net, usb

I need to emulate insertion and removal of SD cards to write tests. What is the best way/tool to implement it in .NET?

Comment: consider asking on http://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mbx, done: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1711/usb-storage-emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://www.lvr.com/usbfaq.htm) page:

> #### How can my application reset, disable, or restart a USB device?
>
> > The DevCon example in the **[WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487463.aspx)** is a command-line utility that shows how to enable, disable, restart, update, remove and query devices using the SetupAPI and CfgMgr32 API functions.

I'm pretty sure this will cause insertion/removal events provided that a card is physically inserted.